# Unable to run angular app on localhost. Failed to load resource vendor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I am able to compile code successfully. But when I serve application using
'node --max-old-space-size=8192'
It compiles successfully. But when I open app in browser it gives
Cannot find resource vendor.js

[image]
I have tried reinstalling node and angularcli
Tried in multiple browsers but no luck

Following are versions I am using

```
`Angular CLI: 8.3.25
Node: 10.19.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core 8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics 8.3.25
@angular/cdk 8.2.3
@angular/cli 8.3.25
@angular/flex-layout 8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material 8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack 8.3.25
@schematics/angular 8.3.25
@schematics/update 0.803.25
rxjs 6.4.0
typescript 3.5.3
webpack 4.39.2`
```

Code compiles successfully with following output

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --port 4200 --host 127.0.0.1 --disableHostCheck true
WARNING: Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://127.0.0.1:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory~projects-global-das~5d5ab8ed} default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory~proj
ects-global-das~5d5ab8ed.js, default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory~projects-global-das~5d5ab8ed.js.map (default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-cra
sh-plan-module-ngfactory~projects-global-das~5d5ab8ed) 386 kB [rendered]
chunk {default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory~projects-global-das~cf85ff3c} default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory~proj
ects-global-das~cf85ff3c.js, default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory~projects-global-das~cf85ff3c.js.map (default~projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-cra
sh-plan-module-ngfactory~projects-global-das~cf85ff3c) 646 kB [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.07 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 130 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory} projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory.js, projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-
crash-plan-module-ngfactory.js.map (projects-global-dashboard-backups-crash-plan-crash-plan-module-ngfactory) 180 kB [rendered]
chunk {projects-global-dashboard-companies-companies-companies-module-ngfactory} projects-global-dashboard-companies-companies-companies-module-ngfactory.js, projects-global-dashboard-companies-companies
-companies-module-ngfactory.js.map (projects-global-dashboard-companies-companies-companies-module-ngfactory) 275 kB [rendered]
chunk {projects-global-dashboard-feedback-feedback-module-ngfactory} projects-global-dashboard-feedback-feedback-module-ngfactory.js, projects-global-dashboard-feedback-feedback-module-ngfactory.js.map (
projects-global-dashboard-feedback-feedback-module-ngfactory) 623 kB [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 9.82 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 22.2 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-04-10T11:01:25.887Z - Hash: a5225c1b1f84947d575b - Time: 113055ms
 Angular Live Development Server is listening on 127.0.0.1:4200, open your browser on http://127.0.0.1:4200/ 
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check your index.html file. Does it have `<base href="/">`

Comment: thanks for your response
yes it does have <base href="/">

Comment: that gives 
javascript memory out of heap
that's why we use
'node --max-old-space-size=8192

Answer (score 0):

Please check the nginx log where you could find permission issue.

Nginx:

tail -f /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log

Read/Write Access:

sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp/

The above command solves the issue.